# sbt: play scala starter example build fails

Tags: sbt

I am new to play and sbt

I downloaded the play-starter-example.

The build file is as follows:

```
 name := """play-scala-starter-example"""

 version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

 lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

 resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")

 scalaVersion := "2.12.7"

 crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.11.12", "2.12.7")

 libraryDependencies += guice
  libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "3.1.2" % Test
 libraryDependencies += "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.197"
```

Then sbt run shows the exception shown below.

**Questions**

1. why is it seeking dependencies from my local maven repository?
2. why is is seeking something as specific as a spotify dependency?
3. how should I address this issue and get the demo to run? (This is meant to be a simple out the box demo of play)

Thanks in advance

```
 Loading project definition from
 C:\Users\jake\__workspace\scalaProjects\play-scala-starter-example\project
 [info] Updating
 ProjectRef(uri("file:/C:/Users/jake/__workspace/scalaProjects/play-scala-starter-example/project/"),
 "play-scala-starter-example-build")... [warn] 
 :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn]  ::         
 UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         :: [warn] 
 :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn]  ::
 commons-io#commons-io;2.5:
 org.apache.commons#commons-parent;39!commons-parent.pom(pom.original)
 origin location must be absolute:
 file:/C:/Users/jake/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/39/commons-parent-39.pom
 [warn]  :: org.apache.commons#commons-compress;1.14:
 org.apache#apache;18!apache.pom(pom.original) origin location must be
 absolute:
 file:/C:/Users/jake/.m2/repository/org/apache/apache/18/apache-18.pom
 [warn]  :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn] [warn] 
 Note: Unresolved dependencies path: [warn]         
 commons-io:commons-io:2.5 [warn]            +-
 com.spotify:docker-client:8.9.0
```

Comment: You should read up on sbt first and come back when your questions are a bit more specific.

Comment: will do, although the sbt documentation on dependencies isn't super-helpful. ... and for a Maven user such as myself the error is a little confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that deleting the ./ivy directory resolved the issue